# mvc5 create new css doesn't working

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-5

```
    <div id="asdf">
    <div class="asdf">
        <h1>@Html.ActionLink("GaramStone","Index")</h1>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="~/Views/Home/About.cshtml">About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="~/Views/Home/Contact.cshtml">Contacts</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

i wanna check new css is applied.

```
    #asdf {
    background:#0094ff
}
```

i made new css file in content directory
and add in bundleconfig.cs

```
 bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/AllCss.css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css",
                  "~/Content/homepage.css"));
```

and add in head tag

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/AllCss.css")
```

But background color doesn't changed. I want to check that if this is a my css code issue or if the new css file does not apply. So I copied site.css code and pasted in hompage.css
and change bundleconfig.cs like this

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/AllCss.css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/homepage.css"));
```

But it doesn't change too...  I can't find what is wrong.

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? How do you reference that on your page? Did you clear cache (If not try Ctrl+F5)?

Comment: I think new css file doesn't render, yes i clear cache.

Comment: Please can you verify that you are not getting any error in browser console when you run the application.

Comment: i'm sorry it is my first time to use mvc5. So i don't know well. In console there are Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND error. when i remove hompage.css(my custom css) and copy the hompage code to site.css it has same error but it work correctly...

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the bundle to your `_layout.cshtml`?

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Content/AllCss.css")
```

Comment: Do you see the CSS-file you added in your solution explorer? If not, click in the right top of your solution explorer on the "multiple files icon" (It says 'show all files' when you hover over it). Then right click on your css file and select "include in project". I think the project is not able to find the CSS-file because it hasn't been included yet.

Comment: Thank you. But It is included. I excluded it and included it again, but the result is same...